# Convert a list of dataframes to a single dataframe with an id column

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list like below.

```
p1

$ColA
     Var1 Freq
1   asgfg  2.1
2     dds  2.1
3     dfg  4.3
4     dfh  2.1

$ColB
  Var1 Freq
1    A 44.7
2    B 55.3
```

What I need looks like below. Basically, I want to combine them into a single dataframe.

```
df

Col      Var1   Freq
ColA     asgfg  2.1
ColA     dds    2.1
ColA     dfg    4.3
ColA     dfh    2.1
ColB      A     44.7
ColC      B     55.3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(p1, .id = 'Col')
#   Col  Var1 Freq
#1 ColA asgfg  2.1
#2 ColA   dds  2.1
#3 ColA   dfg  4.3
#4 ColA   dfh  2.1
#5 ColB     A 44.7
#6 ColB     B 55.3
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
out <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, Col = names(p1), p1))
row.names(out) <- NULL
```

#### data

```
p1 <- list(ColA = structure(list(Var1 = c("asgfg", "dds", "dfg", "dfh"
), Freq = c(2.1, 2.1, 4.3, 2.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4")), ColB = structure(list(Var1 = c("A", "B"), Freq = c(44.7, 
55.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2")))
```

Comment: Perfect. But I get error message ````Warning messages:
1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
3: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector````

Comment: @DevP It is a warning message.  Nothing to worry about it.  Occurs when you have `factor` columns.  If it is a `character` columns, there is no issue with unequal factors.  Please check the `data` in my post

Comment: @DevP It is not an error message.  Error will not give an output

Comment: is there a way to get the `col` column using `plyr::rbind.fill(p1)`?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` package:

```r
data.table::rbindlist(p1, idcol = "col")
```

or using `purrr`:

```r
purrr::map_df(p1, I, .id = "col")
```

Getting:

```r
#     col  Var1 Freq
# 1: ColA asgfg  2.1
# 2: ColA   dds  2.1
# 3: ColA   dfg  4.3
# 4: ColA   dfh  2.1
# 5: ColB     A 44.7
# 6: ColB     B 55.3
```

<sub>Using the data provided in *[akrun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58189974/6461462)*</sub>